# cakephp installation composer error

Tags: cakephp, terminal, installation, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

1. I'm new to cakephp, when I try to install composer using curl, 
   "curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php", 
   I don't know where I supposed to install it in terminal, I mean which directory in terminal ?
2. I got an  error and the error is "The json extension is missing. Install it or recompile php without --disable-json "

Comment: "installation composer error" - and the error is? Read this, the *whole* page http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html Also the official CakePHP documentation contains a step by step (yes, you can even copy and past the commands) instruction how to set it up using composer.

Comment: The error is "The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json
"

Answer (score 1):

1. you just download it anywhere like Download or Home
   but to access composer globally you have to move it `/usr/local/bin`

> sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

now you can use composer just typing composer on terminal.
[more info](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)

2. you just need to install this module

> sudo apt-get install php5-json